# RewriteRule rule for old url to new url add question mark in the url codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect `residential-property/20/old_value` to `/residential-properties/new_value` for this I have written code in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^residential-property/20/old_value?$ /residential-properties/new_value? [B,NE,R=301,L,NC]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Actually 301 direct all index.php requests
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# this gets rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The above code redirect the old url but it also add ? in the url like this `https://example.com.com/?/residential-properties/new_value/`, I don't want to add that question in the url what i am doing wrong please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test `/residential-property/20/old_value` URL from a new browser

Comment: What is that pattern means to match? `^residential-property/20/old_value?$` The trailing `?` in there won't match a literal `?`. Actually such a literal `?` will _never_ occur in a URL, it is not a valid character in there.